# Returning from inside DispatchQueue Swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I am building a function that takes a `CLLocation` parameter and returns a Weather Forecast of type `DarkSkyResponse` which I have defined myself.

```
public func getForecast(at location: CLLocation) -> DarkSkyResponse {
    let request = DarkSkyRequest(key: "KEYGOESHERE")
    let point = DarkSkyRequest.Point(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

    guard let url = request.buildURL(point: point) else {
        preconditionFailure("Failed to construct URL")
    }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        data, response, error in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let data = data else {
                fatalError("No Data Recieved")
            }
            guard let forecast = DarkSkyResponse(data: data) else {
                fatalError("Decoding Failed")
            }
            return forecast
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Everything works perfectly and I just want to return the `forecast` variable found inside the DispatchQueue. When I tried to do this I was met with the following error:
`Unexpected non-void return value in void function`
I believe that this is because I am returning inside of the DispatchQueue.

To try and fix this I moved the data task and decoding process into it's own function that has a completion handler. When I call the function I just have the closure set to return the output as so:

```
public func getForecast(at location: CLLocation) -> DarkSkyResponse {
    let request = DarkSkyRequest(key: "KEYGOESHERE")
    let point = DarkSkyRequest.Point(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

    guard let url = request.buildURL(point: point) else {
        preconditionFailure("Failed to construct URL")
    }

    func getDataAndDecode(from url: URL, completionBlock: @escaping (DarkSkyResponse) -> Void) -> Void {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            data, response, error in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let data = data else {
                    fatalError("No Data Recieved")
                }
                guard let forecast = DarkSkyResponse(data: data) else {
                    fatalError("Decoding Failed")
                }
                completionBlock(forecast)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    getDataAndDecode(from: url) { (output) in
        return output
    }
}
```

Now I get a warning saying: `Expression of type 'DarkSkyResponse' is unused`. I am doing this the correct way or is there a more elegant way of returning the value I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for now, swift doesn’t support yet for async await style (similar to javascript), that means you can’t return directly from async operation.
You better put the callback(completionBlock) argument at *getForecast* method. And it would be nicely if the callback also handle the error case(e. g. *onSuccess* and *onError*). And don’t forget to set getForecast method as void method.

So it would be like these :

```
func getForecast(at location: CLLocation, onSuccess: (DarkSkyResponse) -> (), onError: (Error) -> ()) {

...
}
```

Comment: Or you may consider using RxSwift by utilize relay operator to get the result.